# How to use parallel make when compiling R packages?

Tags: r, makefile, parallel-processing

When using the `make` tool directly, one can use the `-j` option to build in parallel.

How can I use parallel build when installing an R package using `install.packages()`? `make` is invoked by R, not by me, so I can't pass the `-j` option to it. Setting `export MAKE_FLAGS=-j4` before starting R did not work. I am looking to set up parallel build permanently for my R installation.

Comment: `MAKE_FLAGS` is not a variable make knows or cares about.  Maybe you mean `MAKEFLAGS`?

Comment: @MadScientist You are right, it was a silly mistake ... if I set `MAKEFLAGS`, it works fine. I would vote to close this, but there is a useful answer already.

Answer (score 4):

The `options(Ncpus=8)` route is one way. In `install.packages()` you have `Ncpus = getOption("Ncpus")` and that option is described as

Ncpus: the number of parallel processes to use for a parallel
install of more than one source package.  Values greater than
one are supported if the ‘make’ command specified by
‘Sys.getenv("MAKE", "make")’ accepts argument ‘-k -j Ncpus’.

I don't see it listed in `update.packages()` but it functions that same way on my Linux machines so builds generally happen in parallel.

In short, this uses parallel builds of multiple packages, as opposed to `make -j ...` when just building one package. I tried that route too but found the gains less compelling.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the possibility to install multiple packages in parallel. I am still interested in parallel make though. Since you say that you tried it, can you share how to make it work?

Comment: I meant 'triied different ways none of which worked well enough'.  The R Admin + Inslallation manual has a fiew hints about `make -j` (plus other options) so feel free to experiment -- and please report back if you find something works.

Answer (score 2):

Given `n` the number of parallel thread you want to use.

To compile in parallel the different source files of a single package:

```
Sys.setenv(MAKEFLAGS = paste0("-j",n))
```

To compile in parallel different packages all installed through a single `install.packages` call:

```
options(Ncpus = n)
```

To parallelize apply-type functions with parallel::lcmlapply:

```
options(mc.cores =  n)
```

You can put those options in `$HOME/.Rprofile` to have them loaded when R starts.

If you use RStudio and you exported `MAKEFLAGS` in `$HOME/.bashrc`, notice that `.bashrc` is **not** sourced by RStudio when it starts and R session.

Finally you can use

```
parallel::detectCores()
```

to find the number of cores of your operating system, and something like

```
n <- max(parallel::detectCores() - 2L, 1L)
```

to use all the available cores except two.